# What do these two words mean? In a Shloka of Brihat Parashara Hora Shastra?

Tags: astrology, sanskrit

[image: BPHS Chapter 3: GrahaSwarupa Shloka 49-50]

I was looking at BPHS and couldn't make sense of these two padas:

> भागा दश त्रयोऽष्टाश्व्यस्तिथ्योऽक्षा भमिता नखाः ।

I get these meanings:
10, 3, 8...*, 15 (tithis), 5(Akshas/sense organs), 20(Nails on a body).

Ashtaashvya is supposed to be 28 according to the translation
Bhamitaa is also supposed to be 27

But I just can't make sense how Ashvya +or* 8 is going to result in 28? Does ashvya mean 20? if yes then how?

Also, what is bhamitaa?

Edit: I found out that another word for Nakshatra is भासन्ती, so bhamitaa, most likely refers to that, since it is 27.

Comment: 10,3 etc. are referring to degrees where the respective planets get the highest exalted state. For example Sun is exalted in Aries and highest exaltation point as at 10 degree of Aries.. Similarly for Moon it is 3 degree point in Taurus and so on.

Comment: @Rickross 
I'm aware of that and can understand basic English, my question wasn't what the translation means, but rather how the translators came to the conclusion of 28 from the base text of 'ऽष्टाश्व्य'.

What's the reasoning there? For eg, the नखाः in the text refers to nails, of which there are 20 in a body, so therefore the translators have put in 20degrees. But how does that work with 28? Is the puzzling part, to me.

Comment: Okay I see ... @Dushyant